# Pointer understanding in C

Tags: c

I am having a bit of a problem understanding the following code which uses pointers. The code is made for `AVR uC ATMega328pb`. The code is written for reading values of sine from 0-255 on every 100ms and writing those values in compare flag. Then when Counter reaches the compare flag, it enables the ISR (interrupt service routine) which dims the LCD based on compare flag from 0-255, 255 being highest brightness.

First there is sine definition: 
PS.: The code is working correctly

```
char SIN_SAMPLE_LENGTH 40;
uint8_t sinOut[] = {0, 1, 6, 13, 24, 37, 52, 69, 88, 107, 127, 147, 166, 185, 202, 217, 230, 241, 248, 253, 255, 253, 248, 241, 230, 217, 202, 185, 166, 147, 127, 107, 88, 69, 52, 37, 24, 13, 6, 1};
uint8_t *sinSample = sinOut;
```

As i know pointer `*sinSample` stores memory address of `sinOut`, but shouldn't be there `&sinOut`?

Then i have a main loop

```
int main(void)
{
    int cnt = 0; //count
    sei();
    Init_IO();
    Init_T0();

    while(1)
    {
        if(HasOneMillisecondPassed()){ //function returns true when one millisecond passes
            cnt++; //counting up on 1ms count

            if(cnt >= 100){  // when it reaches 100ms do this
                cnt = 0; //restore count on 0

                if(sinSample >= sinOut + SIN_SAMPLE_LENGTH){ 

                    sinSample = sinOut;
                }else{
                    sinSample++;
                }

                OCR0A = *sinSample; 

            }
        }
    }
}

void Init_T0()
{
    OCR0A = *sinOut;
    TCCR0A = (1 << WGM01) | (1 << WGM00) | (1 << COM0A1) | (1 << COM0A0);
    TCCR0B= (1 << CS00) | (1 << CS01);
    TIMSK0 = (1 << OCIE0A);
}
```

i dont understand the part from

`if(sinSample >= sinOut + SIN_SAMPLE_LENGTH)`

until the

`OCR0A = *sinSample`

more specifically, how does `sinOut + SIN_SAMPLE_LENGTH` effect the if statement and what is the meaning of `sinSample = sinOut;`

Thank you!

Comment: "As i know pointer *sinSample stores memory address of sinOut" - You know very wrong! A `char` hould never be used to store a pointer. (luckily the line does not.) In case you mean `sinSample` (without the dereference operator): not exactly, and that's your problem. Arrays and pointers are not the same! Read the chapter in your favourite C book, it is vital!

Comment: And the pointer is `sinSample`, not `*sinSample`; `*sinSample` is of type `int`.

Comment: @olaf Thank you for pointing that out, i will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sinSample` is a pointer to the current element in the `sinOut` array. It starts out pointing to the first element of the array when you do:

```
uint8_t *sinSample = sinOut;
```

Every time the program does:

```
sinSample++;
```

it points to the next element of the array.

`sinOut + SIN_SAMPLE_LENGTH` is a pointer to just past the end of the `sinOut` array, since `SIN_SAMPLE_LENGTH` is the number of elements in the array. Therefore,

```
if (sinSample >= sinOut + SIN_SAMPLE_LENGTH)
```

tests whether we've incremented the pointer beyond the end of the array. When this happens, the code sets it back to the beginning of the array. The result is that it keeps cycling through the array.

This is all essentially equivalent to cycling through the array with an index variable, e.g.

```
int sinIndex = 0;
while(1)
{
    if(HasOneMillisecondPassed()){ //function returns true when one millisecond passes
        cnt++; //counting up on 1ms count

        if(cnt >= 100){  // when it reaches 100ms do this
            cnt = 0; //restore count on 0

            if(sinIndex >= SIN_SAMPLE_LENGTH){ 
                sinIndex = 0;
            }else{
                sinIndex++;
            }

            OCR0A = sinOut[sinIndex]; 

        }
    }
}
```

In C, these two expressions are always equivalent:

```
array[index]
```

and:

```
*(array + index)
```

because when an array is used as an R-value in most expressions it decays to a pointer to its first element, and pointer arithmetic counts by the size of the object the pointer points to.

This is fundamental to understanding C pointers and arrays, so go back and reread that chapter in your textbook if it still doesn't sink in.

Comment: Thank you for great explenation. I was confused about the those operators and address manipulation but now i understand it a lot better so thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

1. `uint8_t *sinSample = sinOut;` is correct.  Alternatively, `uint8_t *sinSample = &sinOut[0];`
2. When the pointer `sinSample` reaches the end of the `sinOut` buffer, it is being "wrapped" back to the beginning to make a continuous signal.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically an example of array and pointer semantics being used interchangeably `sinOut + SIN_SAMPLE_LENGTH` is same as `sinOut[SIN_SAMPLE_LENGTH]`  .. 
Alternately you can think of pointer advancement  `sinSample++` as `sinSample[index++]`

Comment: Was about to write the same as a comment.  If this is to be an answer, please supply some working code with it.

Comment: It's equivalent to `&sinOut[SIN_SAMPLE_LENGTH]`

Answer (score 0):

regarding your question:

*As i know pointer *sinSample stores memory address of sinOut, but shouldn't be there &sinOut?*

in C, referring to an array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  so this line:

```
uint8_t *sinSample = sinOut;
```

is assigning the address of the `sinOut` array to `sinSample` so there is no need for the `address of` operator `&`. Therefore, the `address of` operator should not be used.